# Type Found yet returns Zero Properties

Tags: vb.net, types, properties

i have the code below to add all types within the SapbobsCOM Namespace to a list, this is working ok. For The "Documents" Class I wish to add all the Property Names to a second List however this list is always empty.

```
        Dim counter = 1
        Dim allAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        Dim DocumentProps As New List(Of String)
        For Each assem In allAssemblies

            If assem.FullName.Contains("SAPBusinessOneSDK") Then

                Dim x = assem.GetTypes()

                For Each i In x

                    If i.Namespace = "SAPbobsCOM" Then

                        listOfTypes.Add(i)

                        If i.Name = "Documents" Then
                            Dim xi = i.GetProperties
                            For Each prop In xi
                                DocumentProps.Add(prop.Name)
                            Next
                        End If

                    End If

                Next

            End If
        Next
```

From the image below we can See Documents is a valid class with many Properties:

[image: Class Has Properties]

How can i add these properties to the list Correctly?

Interestingly, in the image below we can see "Documents" is listed with isClass = Flase
and isInterface = True, could this be causing the issue? Why does the object browser show it as a Class ?

[image: Not A Class?]